# How to insert a link from an array in refFromURL() - storage firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have a database that contains different headlines and different links to Firebase storage, like in the picture below:

[image]

And I would like this line

```
storage.refFromURL('gs://........./File.jpg')
```

from the code sample below to read the URL (imageUrl) from the database above. Something like

```
storage.refFromURL(imageUrl)
```

but I simply cannot make it. If I write it with `imageUrl` instead of `gs://`, I get an error saying that imageUrl is not recognizable. If I move the code under `listenForItems(itemsRef)`, the app crashes. I'm pretty sure that it is an easy-fix, but my knowledge is simply too weak to figure it out. Can anyone help me with this?

```
//Some code to configure storage and database and other things//
var storage = firebase.storage();
//Here is where I would like to have the gs:// replaced with the link from the database (see below imageUrl under listenForItems(itemsRef))
var storageRef = storage.refFromURL('gs:.............jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  test = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  test = "Error"
});

export default class Events extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    }),
  };
  this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('-Events').limitToLast(5);
}

getRef() {
  return firebase.database().ref();
}

listenForItems(itemsRef) {
  itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
    var items = [];
    snap.forEach((child) => {
      items.push({
        headline: child.val().titlul,
        imageUrl: child.val().imageUrl,
        link: test,
        _key: child.key
      });
    });

    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items),
    });

  });
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
}

render() // Some code that is not relevant for this ...
```

Comment: did you tried doing it like this refFromURL('gs://'+imageUrl); ?

Comment: Not yet, but 'gs://' + imageUrl would give 'gs://gs://xxxxxx.jpg

Comment: oh, I see, I tought imageUrl was just the  url without gs://

Comment: Yeah. They're with gs://. And it appears that I can't call that ``imageUrl`` out of ``listenForItems(itemsRef)``.